# cx_Freeze- ImportError: cannot import name setup

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm using a Windows 7 machine with cx_Freeze 4.3.1 with Python 3.3, both Python and cx_Freeze are 32-bit versions. I've written a setup.py script that looks like this:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup( 

    name = "Macro Generator",
    version = "1.1",
        description = "Writes Macros for you",
        executables = [Executable("program.py")]
      )
```

When I navigate to the setup.py file location and try to create this executable from the command prompt using:

```
python setup.py build
```

I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
ImportError: cannot import name setup
```

I've also tried to build executables out of some of the sample programs provided with the cx_Freeze download, but I receive the same error for those as well. I've uninstalled cx_Freeze and tried a different version, but the error persists.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks, let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Try importing all of cx_Freeze using `import cx_Freeze`, then refer to the modules using cx_Freeze. e.g `cx_Freeze.setup`, `cx_Freeze.Executable`.

Comment: Do you have a file called `cx_Freeze.py` or a `cx_Freeze` folder in the directory where setup.py is? It might be importing the wrong thing.

Comment: Strangely, I just removed import.sys from the setup.py file and it built the executable correctly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I removed `import sys` from my `setup.py` file and the program compiled successfully.