# How do I convert a Python script to an executable *.exe file?

Tags: python, importerror, cx-freeze

I am facing exactly the same problem as this:

[cx_Freeze- ImportError: cannot import name setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771188/cx-freeze-importerror-cannot-import-name-setup)

Just removing "import sys" from `setup.py` can solve this problem, but in my case the error is still there.

I think that Python cannot find the `cx_freeze` module properly.

Let me know if you have any ideas.

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit and I'm using Python version 3.4.1.

setup.py file is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
  name = "Macro Generator",
  version = "1.1",
  description = "Writes Macros for you",
  executables = [Executable("test2.py")]
)
```

The error message I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    import Executables
ImportError: No module named 'Executables'
```

Comment: You have `Executables` but your module is called `Executable` (note: no `s`). Are you sure this isn't a typo?

Comment: I solved this!! with installing Windows x86 MSI Installer (3.3.3)and cx_Freeze-4.3.3.win32-py3.3.msi. I think 32bit python works well on my PC.

Comment: @newbie_py In that case, you should submit and then select that as the answer.