# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'setup' form 'cx_Freeze' "

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm sorry not to use English well.

I made a game with Python 3.7 and pygame.

I tried to build an exe with cx_Freeze version 5.1.1 but an `ImportError` happens...

Someone uploaded a question with the same error but not resolved: [cx_Freeze- ImportError: cannot import name setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771188/cx-freeze-importerror-cannot-import-name-setup).

I tried to change `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable` to `import cx_Freeze` and then use `cx_Freeze.setup` and `cx_Freeze.Executable`, but then an error `setup not in cx_Freeze` happens...

This is my `install.py` code

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import cx_Freeze
setup(
    name = "hello",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "included_files":["UFO.bmp","UFO_Monster.bmp","boss_Atack.jpg","boss.png","background_1.png","bullet.png","boom.png","shot.wav","explosion.wav","mybgm.wav","D2coding.ttf","Meteor.png"]}},
    version = "0.1",
    executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable('Main.py'),
    cx_Freeze.Executable('Boss_class.py'),
    cx_Freeze.Executable('Boss_class_Attack.py'),
    cx_Freeze.Executable('Meteor.py'),
    cx_Freeze.Executable('UFO_class.py'),
    cx_Freeze.Executable('UFO_Monster.py')
]
)
```

This is the error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "cx_Freeze.py", line 2, in 
>           from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
>         File "C:\Users```\source\repos\PythonGame\cx_Freeze.py", line 2, in   
>       from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
>       ImportError: cannot import name 'setup' from 'cx_Freeze' (C:\Users```\source\repos\PythonGame\cx_Freeze.py)

Comment: did you install cx_Freeze with pip ?

Comment: Do you have a file named `cx_Freeze.py` directly in your source directory, instead of importing through a package directory and possibly through the one installed with `pip`? The path shows `cx_Freeze.py` and not the expected path. I'm not sure you'd want to build an executable for each .py either?

Comment: Yes you have named your file `cx_Freeze.py`. Ty changing it to `abc.py` or anything else, but not any library name.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou Thank's alot i solved!

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon Yes. surely

Comment: @MatsLindh my file name is cx_Freeze.py ... It's reason that Errors happend

Comment: @MatsLindh please post your solution as an answer that the OP can then mark as accepted.

Comment: @jpeg OMG thank you edit my Q. very helpful for learning English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file named `cx_Freeze.py` directly in your source directory, instead of importing through a package directory and possibly through the one installed with pip?

The path shows `cx_Freeze.py` and not the expected path from an installed package.

Comment: Yeah.. that install.py file name is cx_Freeze.py ;( It made my code error. Thanks for Answer :)